# Jquery slider multiple div

Tags: jquery, html, slide, slidetoggle, sliders

I have a basic code here which slides/unslides which works fine however as there are 5 divs, if slideToggle() slides open and I click on another link, it will also trigger slideToggle() to open this div also. I want it so it closes the opened div then opens the requested div?

Many thanks

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Portal").click(function(){
    $("#portal").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $("#Profile").click(function(){
    $("#profile").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $("#Stats").click(function(){
    $("#stats").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $("#Teams").click(function(){
    $("#teams").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $("#Matches").click(function(){
    $("#matches").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

        <table width="100%" id="{table}">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              $view_portal
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Profile">Profile</div></th>
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Stats">Stats</div></th>
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Teams">My Teams</div></th>
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Matches">My Matches</div></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>

                <div id="portal" style="display: none;">$my_portal</div>
                <div id="profile" style="display: none;">Profile</div>
                <div id="stats" style="display: none;">Stats</div>
                <div id="teams" style="display: none;">Teams</div>
                <div id="matches" style="display: none;">Matches</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off giving your elements a class, then you can attach a single click handler:

```
<div id="profile" class="navigation">Profile</div>
<div id="profile-content" class="content">Profile content show/hide</div>
```

Then attach a click handler to `navigation`:

```
$('div.navigation').on('click', function() {
  $('#' + this.id + '-content').slideToggle().siblings('.content').slideUp();
});
```

Using the `id` of the clicked element, you can get the corresponding content by appending `-content` to the selector (in the example above you'd end up with `#profile-content`). You can then `slideToggle()` on that element, and simply `slideUp()` all siblings with the `.content` class.

#### [Here's a simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sS4wt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If this were my code I would probably add some type of additional selector and use a single jQuery handler.

```
<style type="text/css">
 .mypanel {display:none;}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mytrigger").click(function(){
    $(".mypanel:visible").hide();
    $($(this).data("panel")).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

        <table width="100%" id="{table}">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              $view_portal
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Profile" class="mytrigger" data-panel="#profile">Profile</div></th>
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Stats" class="mytrigger" data-panel="#stats">Stats</div></th>
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Teams" class="mytrigger" data-panel="#teams">My Teams</div></th>
              <th width="$tbl_head_width%"><div id="Matches" class="mytrigger" data-panel="#matches">My Matches</div></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>

                <div id="portal" class="mypanel">$my_portal</div>
                <div id="profile" class="mypanel">Profile</div>
                <div id="stats" class="mypanel">Stats</div>
                <div id="teams" class="mypanel">Teams</div>
                <div id="matches" class="mypanel">Matches</div>
```

If you were unable modify the code in that structure you could simply add a class called selected (or something) and then hide controls with that class before you slideToggle.